# React native local development server pictures

Tags: macos, react-native, kubernetes

I have a server which responsible for serving user images. It's running on my laptop and it's available locally under some arbitrary name:

```sh
192.168.xxx.yyy local.minikube.com
```

I want to mimic production as much as possible so my local server also runs ingress, from my laptop I can access images through some URL like:

```
htpp://local.minikube.com/static/img/A.png
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to retrieve these images from my connected (android) device (without changing images URLs of course)? I'm using the [Avatar](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/avatar/) from react-native-elements (it's based on regular [Image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#prefetch)).

```
<Avatar source={{ uri: 'htpp://local.minikube.com/static/img/A.png' }} />
```

I guess it must be possible because `fetch` requests can use the locally defined host simply by using react native debug mode (I suppose the javascript interpreter is running on my laptop and therefore the `local.minikube.com` host is known). Sadly it apparently doesn't work for images fetches.

More precisely, what I want to avoid is to have to 1) port forward to my local server together with 2) adb reverse to the forwarded port.

Comment: Does this help? https://georgik.rocks/how-to-add-custom-mapping-of-hostname-to-ip-in-android-emulator/

Comment: I'm using a physical device so I'm not sure, I'll try.

Comment: Oh, i thought you are using an emulator. I'm not sure if you can do this without rooting your android device since you can't edit hosts without root permission, sorry.

Comment: At least I learned that I could connect to my device using `adb shell`.

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure if you can get a answer here, you might want to open a second question on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Also, you don't want to change image urls but, you can use [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) library to create two .env files for production and development where you enter the domain for production and local ip address for development. And get image server domain from react-native-config

Comment: If you are using K8s (assuming you are since you're using minikube), you need to create a Service of type `LoadBalancer` to expose your resources to outside traffic. Please include your manifest files for deployment and services. Doing so would make it easier to find a suitable solution for your usecase.

Comment: @p10l ahh ok ok, I wasn't aware minikube had an option for this ([tunel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/)). I'll try tomorow but I'm afraid it will be hard to have a static "fake" host name (I'll still have a DNS problem, I fail to see how my phone will translate `local.minikube.com` to the load balancer's IP.